# How to include js- and php- code in layout properly via Assets in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I need to add google tag manager (Gtag) to all pages (modules) of the project. Gtag-code consists of 3 files:

```
- 2 files with js-code, that needs to be included in <head> tag,
- 1 file with <noscript> tags that need to be included in <body> tag.
```

Each module of my project contains `layout.php` and `AppAsset.php`. js-files in these layouts need to be included in `<body>` tag.

So, I created `GlobalAppAsset.php`, define `$js`-property there:

```
class GlobalAppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $js = [
        'js/gtag_script1.js',
        'js/gtag_script2.js',
    ];

    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
}
```

`AppAsset.php` for each module in project I inherit from `GlobalAppAsset.php` and now I need to merge its `$js` with `$js`-property in `GlobalAppAsset.php`. How can I do it properly?

Also, I need that `AppAsset.php`'s js-files be included in `<body>`-section of the layout, and `GlobalAppAsset.php`'s $js-files be included in `<head>`-section. How can I this?

And finally, I need to include Gtag's php-file with `<nonscript>`-part of gtag in `<body>`. Is it possible to do it with Assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it will be better to use [`$depends`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetbundle#$depends-detail) property in your AppAsset instead of extending the GlobalAppAsset.

You can leave GlobalAppAsset as is and the AppAsset should look like this:

```php
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    //... other app assets configuration

    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_BEGIN];
    public $depends = [
        //... some other dependencies
        \fully\qualified\GlobalAppAsset::class
    ];
}
```

As for including the noscript snippet the assets are not a best way how to do that.
There might be some way, for example overriding the `register()` method to register `yii\web\View::EVENT_BEGIN_BODY` then outputing the snippet in the registered event handler.

```php
class GlobalAppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';

    public $js = [
        'js/gtag_script1.js',
        'js/gtag_script2.js',
    ];

    public $jsOptions = ['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];

    public static function register($view) {
        parent::register($view);
        $view->on(
            \yii\web\View::EVENT_BEGIN_BODY,
            function($event) use ($view) {
                echo $view->render('the-view-with-noscript');
            }
        )
    }
}
```

This solution might work but because this solution is not exactly standard it might cause issues with maintaining the code later.

The better solution for that would be using a widget but you will need to run the widget in each of your layout files.

Comment: Wow great, use $depends property!

Comment: that is a nice answer i never thought of that +1

Comment: Now that i think about it, i'm not sure if the `register()` method is called when the asset bundle is registered only as dependency. If it's not called you might need to move the event registration to `init()` method and access view object as `Yii::$app->view`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$cssOptions` to include the file inside the `<noscript>` tag like below

```
public $cssOptions = ['noscript' => true];
```

see [HERE](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#asset-options) for details

EDIT

As its not a css file that you want to wrap inside the `<noscript>` tag, and you have multiple modules and you dont want to write it inside eacho of the layout files, a better approach would be to create a separate view file with your code

google-tag.php

```
 <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) --> <noscript> <iframe src="googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe> </noscript> <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

and include it using

```
$this->render('google-tag')
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! My php-file that I need to register in EVERY layout: 
    <!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript>
        <iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
     </noscript>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->

How can I register it via assets?

Comment: i wont recommend using the `Assets` file for including the `iframe` that you have specified you can include it manually inside the head tag within the layout file @Dmitry , apart from it is there any special reason you want it to be included via `Assets` class?

Comment: The problem is I have multiple modules and I need to include iframe-code to each of it. Yes, I can include code manually, but I'm trying to find universal solution that helps me include code once. Maybe there is another way except Assets?

Comment: then you can create a separate view file with the iframe code and include it using `$this->render('your_view_name')` inside your layouts , would that be a better approach that would work for you ? @Dmitry as i dont find any other option to do that other than these 2

Comment: yes, I alreary did it. But a thought there is a way to include iframe once in some place instead of include it manually in every module.

Comment: And maybe you can help me with another question - how can i specify that some js-files includes in ```<head>``` and ```<some>``` in body via Asset?

Comment: @Dmitry then the last resort would be to inject the code via javascript

Comment: about the other question, please add a separate post so both of the questions are targetted into their own thread @Dmitry